# How to build custom validation and/or change input value to be validated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a custom data field validation that validate mobile number.
sometimes i can change the input safely and that is valid for me.
How can i change the field value while i'm validating?

Comment: Have you heard of my good friend `Regex`?

Comment: Thank you @Matt but mobile number may start with + or 0 or both and all of them are valid for me and i want to format the entry to a same value everytime

Comment: For validation you can build custom validation attribure or use RegularExpressionAttribute [Model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2). It is not right use ValidationAttribute to change input. You can use Custom Model Binder for input change [Custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)